# Плохо()усваиваемый; плохо()выводимый; медленно()выводимый. Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Плохо усваиваемые продукты;

плохо выводимые вещества;

медленно выводимые вещества.

Answer (score 3):

Раздельно, хотя причины для слитного написания [сложных прилагательных - терминов](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm) есть. Описаны с примерами у Розенталя.

Другое дело, что в приводимых им первых частях таких прилагательных нет *плохо* и *медленно*...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако... я вспомнила и нашла термин [медленнорастущий](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9)... И тогда почему бы не предположить, что у медиков может использоваться словосочетание *медленновыводимые* вещества? Но проверить это негде.

---

Ещё одна отсебятинка.

Если в приведенных Вами *плохо усваиваемых продуктах* и *плохо выводимых веществах* наречие "плохо" заменить на "трудно", то термины легко обнаруживаются: [трудновыводимые](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9) пятна, [трудноусваиваемые](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B) углеводы.

---

P. S. Не словарь, но прецедент: [быстровыводимый - медленновыводимый](http://vmede.org/sait/?page=7&id=Farmakologiya_klin_farmakoter_kukes_srar_2012&menu=Farmakologiya_klin_farmakoter_kukes_srar_2012)...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Причин для слитного написания нет.

Пишутся раздельно словосочетания, состоящие из наречия и прилагательного или причастия, напр.:плохо скрываемый,свободно конвертируемый.

См.: Академический справочник. § 131.

Comment: Вообще-то в указанном контексте нет причин для **раздельного** написания. Хайль Розенталь!

Comment: Lazy Badger, а можно тоже самое но без "хайль"? Не все такое понимают.

Comment: Серж, "быстрорастворимый" тоже раздельно? Или тут причины есть? )))

Comment: быстрорастворимый - термин зафиксированный словарем. Вопрос в том, что считать термином, что - нет. У Лопатина, кстати, это оговаривается. Как вы напишите: трудно перевариваемые продукты ( слитно или раздельно)?

Comment: Словарь - всего лишь индикатор того, что причина таки есть. Если вы рассматриваете словарь как догму, причем довольно вольно эту догму трактуя, то вынужден вас разочаровать. Словари *фиксируют* правила.

Comment: Словарь фиксирует правила, тем самым узаконивая то или иное написание. а правила, кстати, я привел.

Answer (score 1):

Рина, спорить на эту тему можно бесконечно.
Дело в том, что правила на этот счет весьма расплывчаты. Если попытаться вынести некоторый конструктив, то подобные сочетания пишутся слитно, если используются как термины (обычно научно-технические). Все ваши примеры вполне могут рассматриваться как таковые, а могут и не рассматриваться. Поэтому все в руках автора. 
Лично я сочетания с "плохо" (не только ваши) как термины не воспринимаю, если нет словарной фиксации, но в отношении конкретно ваших примеров допускаю терминологичность. 
А сочетания с медленно/быстро с оттенком терминологичности пишу слитно почти всегда, за что и получаю нагоняи.
Так что в ваших примерах я за слитное написание.